# misplaced strings echo PHP

Tags: php

```
<table id="profil_table">
<?php
$req_album = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM album WHERE idUser = ?");
$req_album->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$cpt = 0;
do{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $resultat = $req_album->fetch();
       if(isset($resultat['nom'])){
       echo "<a href=\"album_page.php?id=".$_GET['id']."\"><td><img src=\"img/".$userinfo['pseudo']."/".$resultat['nom']."/couverture".".".$resultat['typePhotoCouv']."\"/>".$resultat['nom']."</td></a>";
       $cpt++;
    }else{
       echo "<td></td>";
    }
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     }while(isset($resultat['nom']));
if($cpt == 0){
    echo "<div id=\"vide\">Vous n'avez toujours pas publié d'album!</div>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Do you see what i print after the if statement : `isset($resultat['nom'])`

Well here is what it prints out:

[image: image1]

The "a" tag is printed out of the php code. How is this even possible?

Any ideas?

Comment: Because of the `<td></td>` that's why. So place the `<td>` before your href tag. and the `</a>` inside the td tags.

Comment: The final DOM tree as shown isn't the HTML source code it comes from. To see that you need to hit Ctrl+U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out
Place your **<a>** inside **<td>**

```
<table id="profil_table">
<?php
$req_album = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM album WHERE idUser = ?");
$req_album->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$cpt = 0;
do{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $resultat = $req_album->fetch();
       if(isset($resultat['nom'])){
       echo "<td><a href=\"album_page.php?id=".$_GET['id']."\"><img src=\"img/".$userinfo['pseudo']."/".$resultat['nom']."/couverture".".".$resultat['typePhotoCouv']."\"/>".$resultat['nom']."</a></td>";
       $cpt++;
    }else{
       echo "<td></td>";
    }
     }
     echo "</tr>";
     }while(isset($resultat['nom']));
if($cpt == 0){
    echo "<div id=\"vide\">Vous n'avez toujours pas publié d'album!</div>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `a` element is not allowed as a direct child of a `tr` element. The [only allowed children](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html) are `td` or `th` elements. What's happening is that your browser is re-jigging your generated HTML, doing its best to make it legal as it converts the HTML you've sent it into a real [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree in memory.

You should "view source" in your browser to see your actual generated source; the view you've posted is presumably the in-memory DOM tree that your browser has finally generated.

The solution would be to move the `a` element inside the `td`.